# How can I JOIN tables in different databases (on the same server) using Slick?

Tags: join, database-connection, slick

I'd like to do a join on two tables residing in different databases on the same MySQL server, using Slick 2.0. Usually this would just be a matter of referring to the tables via a qualified name, e.g. `DB1.TABLE1`.

> Can someone show me how to do this in Slick?

If I don't specify a database in the JDBC connection string, I get an exception. If I do specify one of the databases there, say `DB1`, and specify the table name in the `Table` constructors as `DB1.TABLE1` and `DB2.TABLE2`, then I get an exception about the missing table `DB1.DB2.TABLE2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify any database in the connection string and pass the database as the `schema` argument to `Table` for each table class.

```
class SomeTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int,String)](
  tag, Some("SOME_DB"), "SOME_TABLE"
) {
  def id = column[Int]("id")
  def title = column[String]("title")
  def * = (id, title)
}
```

This should really be documented somewhere: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/659