# Join tables in different databases using Slick 2 (with auto generated data model)

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick, play-slick

I have a Scala/Play application and I need to join tables from 2 different PostgreSQL databases on the same server using Slick 2. The databases are massive so I don't create classes for my tables manually, I use [Slick 2 schema code generator](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/code-generation.html), so if there need to be changes made it has to work with the code generator.

Instead of defining my db url in the conf like this

```
db.pg1.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db1"
db.pg2.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db2"
...
```

I'd like to do it like this:

```
db.pg.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432"
```

and then my method would look something like this:

```
def test = DB("pg").withDynSession { //not sure if this is 100% correct
    //query joining two tables from different databases here
}
```

As in, connect to the server, but not a particular database, so that I could work with multiple databases using the same connection. Is this possible? I use this approach already with Slick Plain SQL and it works just fine. Side question: would this have some negative impact on performance?

If what I want to accomplish is possible, can you please provide me with a simple example. If this is not possible, what are my alternatives? Thanks.

My stack:

- Scala 2.10.3
- Play 2.2.2
- Slick 2.0
- PostgreSQL 9.3.3
- Java 8

Comment: This should work either out-of-the-box or after minor adjustments. Did you try if it "just works"? And if not, where is the problem?

Comment: @cvogt How would this "out-of-the-box" look like? There is nothing to describe this situation in Slick 2 documentation, at least I couldn't find.

Comment: Slick Table classes contain information about which database the corresponding table resides in. You can simply use them together in a query. You said you are already using Slick with the code generator. Doesn't it generate the required classes or where is the problem?

Comment: @cvogt So is it possible to do so without defining a separate connection to each database, instead just defining a connection to the whole DB server (like in my example)? If so then how would that look? Also, let's say that's not possible and I have to manually define a connection to each database, how would the query look then? I can't find any examples whatsoever of a query where two tables from different databases are joined using Slick 2.

Comment: @cvogt In your answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603506/how-can-i-join-tables-in-different-databases-on-the-same-server-using-slick you've posted an example of a table class, however when Slick 2 code generator generates the class - it doesn't include `Some("SOME_DB")`, is there a way to make it include it?